# Apache Poi reading blank colour cells accidently

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've built a Java program that reads data from an Excel spreadsheet, but since improving the visual appearance of the spreadsheet by adding colors the program has been reading in blank cells.

At the moment only about 15 rows are occupied by information, but I need hundreds of rows to remain coloured. What kind of technique should I use to ensure the program only reads occupied cells?

Here is a sample from my program that finds the number of occupied rows. It returns 1019 rather than 15:

```
i = 0;
for (Row row : spreadsheet1) {
  if (row.getCell(0) != null) {
     i += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: get the value of the celll and check if it is an empty string or not

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells

Comment: i do facing this problem. i found out that certain excel version cannot give the style information.. newest version can retrieve by apache poi..